# Plotting Real Time data using Flask Chart.js

Tags: javascript, python, flask, chart.js, real-time

I am sending some data to my Flask server from another application using HTTP requests. I need to plot and display the data on my webpage. The graph needs to update whenever new data comes in. The plot is a real-time plot. So far data transfer is working properly but I am unable to plot the data.
This is my python code

```
@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def main():
   
return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/data', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def data():
    # Using Static data
    #data = [time() * 1000, random() * 100]


    data = [request.json["time"],request.json["value"]]
    print(data)

    response = make_response(json.dumps(data))
    response.content_type = 'application/json'
    return response
```

Using data inside the app, the plot works but when I try to get data from server, it does not work.

The script used for plotting is given below

```html
<script>
        var chart;

        function requestData()
        {
            // Ajax call to get the Data from Flask
            var requests = $.get('/data');


            var tm = requests.done(function (result)
            {
                var series = chart.series[0],
                    shift = series.data.length > 20;

                // add the point
                chart.series[0].addPoint(result, true, shift);

                // call it again after one second
                setTimeout(requestData, 2000);
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'data-container',
                    defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
                    events: {
                        load: requestData
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Live random data'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    tickPixelInterval: 150,
                    maxZoom: 20 * 1000
                },
                yAxis: {
                    minPadding: 0.2,
                    maxPadding: 0.2,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Value',
                        margin: 80
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Random data',
                    data: []
                }]
            });

        });
    </script>
```

I keep getting the error "NoneType" object is not subscript-able. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@app.route('/data', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def data():
    data = [time() * 1000, random() * 100]
    response = make_response(json.dumps(data))
    response.content_type = 'application/json'
    return response
```

I use it in my app and it works.